# maintainscrollpositiononpostback not working with firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, postback

I am using VS 2008. I like the feature maintainscrollpositiononpostback. It works fine with IE 8. But it does not work consistently with Firefox. Sometimes, instead the line I click on goes to the bottom of the page. The field I am trying to refresh is with a div tag with overflow set to auto. Also I have several update panels with updatemode set to conditional. This means only the panel affected should be refreshed. This is also not working in the case on Firefox.

I have searched the web for possible solutions but none of them work for me.

Most of my users use Firefox so this is a problem for me.

Thanks in advance,

Bob

Comment: I sometimes have this problem with Chrome.

Comment: Yes. I find that all the browsers I tried Chrome, Flock and Safari all behave in the same incorrect manner,

Bob

Comment: possible duplicate of [MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback Does Not Work In Firefox 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189769/maintainscrollpositiononpostback-does-not-work-in-firefox-4-0)

Answer (score 2):

scrollsaver to the rescue?
http://en.hasheminezhad.com/scrollsaver

I found this little js file a few weeks ago after implementing Post/Redirect/Get on a few of my pages. It may enable you to turn off maintain on your pages if you throw it in the master. I haven't fully tested it with ff4/5 or chrome...

Answer (score 1):

Edit the Browser Capabilities file, and explicitly set it so that MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback is supported on Safari Browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript for this.. chek it out..

http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewfrederick/archive/2008/03/04/maintain-scroll-position-after-asynchronous-postback.aspx