# MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback Does Not Work In Firefox 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, firefox4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [maintainscrollpositiononpostback not working with firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866770/maintainscrollpositiononpostback-not-working-with-firefox)

MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback stopped working in Firefox 4.  This breaks our websites and needs to be fixed.

I've added the following to our App_Browsers folder in our .NET 4/IIS7 website:

```
<browsers>
  <browser id="Firefox4" parentID="Firefox">
      <identification>
          <capability name="majorversion" match="4" />
      </identification>

      <capabilities>
          <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
      </capabilities>
  </browser>  
</browsers>
```

Yet, support for MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback remains false for Firefox 4.  I've also have tried changing several other properties and none of them are affecting the defaults for firefox.  Please help.